# fnDraw() in datatables.net

Tags: datatables

Can't refresh dataTable by `fnDraw()`
Note: The table is initialised & displayed correctly before clicking the 'refresh' link

```js
function rfsh(){
    var oTable = $('#grd_table').dataTable();
    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='rfsh()'>Refresh Table</a>
```

If I use `oTable.fnClearTable();` It works. The table data gets cleared.

If `oTable.fnDraw();` is used, the table doesn't get refreshed.

What I may be doing wrong in calling `oTable.fnDraw();` ?

Comment: I figured it out. 'sAjaxSource:' was not configured properely. Now it is working correctly.  Regards, Vineet.

Comment: @Vinet, you could answer your own question and accept it - maybe helping other people in the future.